# Dynamically change tab size in GitHub markdown

Tags: github

How do I change how many spaces a `<tab>` character converts into in GitHub's markdown?

I am currently quoting my code with

````
```
````

at the beginning and end of the code block.

Ideally, I could have one code block with a tabstop of 8 and another of 2.